# Get all the data from a clicked node in C3JS

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

How do I get all the data from a node when clicked? Right now I get only the x and value.

How do I get all the values from the JSON data object used for plotting the graph?

```
var chart_scatterplot = c3.generate({tooltip: {
contents: function(d, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color) {

  var company = jsonfile[d[0].index].company;
  var mailCount = jsonfile[d[0].index].mailCount;
  var lastInteractedInDays = jsonfile[d[0].index].lastInteractedInDays;

  var companyData = "<table class='data-c3-table'><tr><td>" + company + "</td></tr><tr><td>" + mailCount + "</td></tr><tr><td>" + lastInteractedInDays + "</td></tr></table>"
  return companyData;
  //return (company+mailCount+lastInteractedInDays) // formatted html as youmailCount want
}},
point: {r: 7},

data: {
json: jsonfile,
x: 'mailCount',
keys: {
  value: ['mailCount', 'lastInteractedInDays'],
},
color: function(color, d) {
  if (d.value > average) {
    return "#F86A52"
  } else {
    return "#49B5A6"
  };
},
type: 'scatter',
onclick: function(d) {
  abc(d);
}
  },axis: {
x: {
  label: 'Interactions',
  tick: {
    fit: false
  }
},
y: {
  label: 'Days'
}},legend: {
show: false}});
var abc = function(v) {console.log("hello" + JSON.stringify(v));}
```

Attached is a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/npmarkunda/eqfyeeh1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the full data associated with the node on click.

```
onclick: function(d) {
  console.log(jsonfile[d.index]);//will console. the clicked node's data.
}
```

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/3ykL6kp3/)

Comment: Thanks again, Cyril.